# Firebase App Distribution Upload error, Missing information about the APK path

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-app-distribution

Having problems when uploading app release apk to firebase using the gradle `./gradlew appDistributionUploadRelease` command in terminal. This issue started after I updated a few of my build tools, updating gms to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'` from 4.3.3, updating to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'` from 3.4.2, I don't know if these updates have anything to do with the issue but ehwn I run the `./gradlew appDistributionUploadRelease` command now, I get an error in the build terminal

```
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:appDistributionUploadRelease FAILED
Found APK at /home/****/agent/workspace/project-name/app/build/intermediates/incremental/packageRelease/tmp/app-release.apk.
Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadRelease'.
> Missing information about the APK path. Please check that an APK path was passed in and try agai
```

I tried explicitly specifying the apkPath in the build gradle to a path with confirmed release but I am still getting this error just with the updated path

```
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:appDistributionUploadRelease FAILED
Found APK at build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk.
Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadRelease'.
> Missing information about the APK path. Please check that an APK path was passed in and try again
```

I am out of ideas on how to fix this issue as I am sure the apk exists in the specified path and the apk works when manually uploaded to firebase. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the issue, this  `classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:2.0.1'` was missing from the dependencies section in my project level `build.gradle`. Follow instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle) to the letter folks.

Comment: I already had the dependency in version `1.3.1`, but I upgraded gradle version and it doesn't work anymore. So I upgrated appdistribution to the last version (`2.1.1` at this date) and it's works again.
So it Could also be a version compatibility problem between gradle and appdistribution

Comment: I working classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:2.0.1'